# Retrieve old value AFTER update

Tags: oracle10g, sql-update

Is it possible to get the old value which was updated to new value by using 'SELECT' statement?

Consider if a value 'NO' in oracle table is updated to 'YES' by simple update statement. Can I get the original value 'No' by using select statement without modifying the original update statement?

Comment: No need for a `SELECT`, just use the `NEW` and `OLD` records. See the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#CIHEIHAC

Comment: Is it possible without using triggers

Comment: You can execute SELECT before UPDATE. Duh!